# How can I send email reminder before 1 day of an event in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, scheduled-tasks

I have three models.

1. CustomUser
2. Webregister
3. Zlink

And following is the code for Zlink in models.py,

```
class Zlink(models.Model):
    customUser = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #foreignkey 1
    webregister = models.ForeignKey(Webregister, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #foreignkey 2
    reg_link = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)
```

"foreignkey 2" gives me the event id and "foreignkey 1" gives me an email address of user.

Among the many fields, one of the field in `Webregister` is `event_starts` that contains date and time of event when it will going to start.

I can get the email address of the user in the event using firing the query,

```
x = Zlink.objects.get(id=1)
x.customUser
```

Now if the user having multiple users then how these email address to send an email of reminder before a day of event ?

Any Clue ? I'm new in django please.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario 1 (If Custom user model has only one email field):

```
x = Zlink.objects.get(id=1)
email_to_list = [x.customUser.email,]
```

Scenario 2 (if Custom user model has two email fields):

```
x = Zlink.objects.get(id=1)
email_to_list = [x.customUser.primary_email, x.customUser.secondary_email]
```

Finally use following code to send mail (Assuming you have working smtp settings defined in settings.py)

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    'from@example.com',
    email_to_list,
    fail_silently=False,
)
```